# Setting up ROS catkin/rosbuild simultaneously

Tags: catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have both a catkin_ws and a rosbuild_ws. However, when I use the command roscd I can only go to the one I've sourced last, i.e.:

-When I do source ~/rosbuild_ws/setup.bash, I the packages inside rosbuild are known, hence I can roscd to them.

-When I do ". ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash", the packages inside catkin are known. But I stop being able to roscd into rosbuild.

This also means that rosbuild cannot use catkin packages and vice versa.

What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214109/setting-up-ros-catkin/rosbuild-simultaneously/) by [Carollour](https://answers.ros.org/users/21953/carollour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [this Tutorial on having a `rosbuild` workspace on top of a `catkin` workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace).

However, note the drawback:

- You cannot depend from a `rosbuild` package on a `catkin` package.

Thus, it would be worthwhile to switch to `catkin` for all packages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0